# ios_base and static members

Tags: c++, static-members

Static constants in the `ios_base` class are initialized when created, which makes sense for constants.  Can non-constant static member variables be initialized the same way, or is this concept only allowed for constant static members?

For non-constant static members with gnu compilers must use always define/allocate space separately from it's deceleration in the header? Is it even proper to initialize constant static members this way?

Comment: +1 for the cool name. And to briefly answer the question, defining/allocating is always required, but the compiler does it automatically for you if you omit the definition of an integral (i.e. `int`, `short`, `long`, `enum`, etc) constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class members can be created and initialized only for the `static const` (integral data type, like `int, char, double` etc.) members in current C++ standard. For non-static member it's not possible. However, in C++0x that facility is introduced.

**Edit**: For non-const static member, you can do initialization but you have to do the same in .cpp file (for non template classes).  e.g.

```
struct A
{
  static const int i = 0; // ok
  static int j;  // can declare in .cpp file as below
  int k = 2; // error, but valid in C++0x
  const int l = 3; // error, valid in C++0x
  static const int m[2] = {1,2}; // error, should be an integral type
  static const string n = "hi"; // error, should be an integral type
};
int A::j = 1  // declare in class body, and define outside
```

Comment: I mean for non-constant static members can you do that as well, and what is meant by intergral data type :-)

Comment: I have edited my answer. hope that will answer your question.

Comment: no problem. types like `const int` and `int&` (reference variables) should be initialized in the initializer list of constructor. For example: in above `struct A`, its member `const int l;` will be initialized as, `A(const int val) : l(val) { ... }`. You can not initialize `l` in the body of constructor method.

Answer (score 1):

> Because static data members must be
>   explicitly defined in exactly one
>   compilation unit.

From C++ FAQ
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12

You might want to read the whole "Constructors" section about "static data member" to clearly understand it.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html

Comment: Very helpful source :-), but how does the standard headers (such as ios_base) have const static memebers defined, but there is no defintion in one compilation unit?